# (ssg-wsg) How to do AES Encryption in SSG-WSG API with Initialization Vector in PHP

Tags: php, api, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt the payload with the AES encryption like below for SSG-WSG API. But I keep getting

> Failed to parse JSON request content

I think something is wrong with my way of encryption. I am doing this in PHP.

```
<pre>
$cipher = "aes-256-cbc"; 
$ekey = "encryption key provided to SSG"

//Generate a 256-bit encryption key 
$encryption_key = $ekey;

// Generate an initialization vector 
$iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher); 
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_size); 

//Data to encrypt 
$data = $f;  // payload in f
$encrypted_data = openssl_encrypt($data, $cipher, $encryption_key, 0, $iv); 

$x = base64_encode($encrypted_data);
</pre>
```

Where is the **SSGAPIInitVector** initialization vector to be used, and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the openssl_encrypt library [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php), the 5th paramenter $iv is for the initialisation vector value. So, I believe you have to replace what you are doing which randomly generates a random Initialisation Vector to the fixed value provided.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).